# Matplotlib can't plot log grid if use gca() parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, logging, grid

I'm trying to customize my plot, everything works fine except plotting the log grid. Any idea how to fix the issue?

```
Fig_Z21 = plt.figure()

plt.loglog(Z21['Frequency']/10e5, Z21['Z21_Mag'], label='Z21')
plt.gca().set_axis_bgcolor('white')
plt.grid(True, which='majorminor', color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.4)
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('black')
plt.gca().yaxis.label.set_color('black')
plt.gca().xaxis.label.set_color('black')
plt.gca().tick_params(axis='x', colors='black')
plt.gca().tick_params(axis='y', colors='black')
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False #Let TeX do the typsetting
plt.xlabel('Frequency [MHz]', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Magnitude', fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `both` as value of `which` in `plt.grid`:

```
plt.grid(True, which='both', color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.4)
```

Comment: And with major or minor alone, does It show the grid?